# How to fix this wall? Is it drywall? Do I take the everything off and start fresh?

Tags: drywall, walls, patch

Very old wires were along the baseboard and I pulled it off and some wall came with it. I, thinking it was wallpaper under the paint kept pulling and this is what I have now. What do I do? Do I leave it as it and get drywall? Continue to take it all off?  I have no idea where to begin, and would like to fix myself if possible. Any ideas? Thanks in advance [image]

Comment: How thick is it?  If not too thick maybe straighten out the edges and paint a nice contrasting colour.

Comment: I think we need a closer photo of that area, in specific of the edges and possibly of that rectangle. I really can't tell what we're looking at.